# convert multiline datatable column to multiline in html table in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have added multiline data to "Service Performed" column in datatable, which I am writing to HTML.

```
Dim row = dt.NewRow()
row("Date") = Display_Date
row("Mileage") = Odometer
    For t1 As Integer = 0 To returnData.serviceHistory.displayRecords(d1).text.Count - 1
         Text(t1) = returnData.serviceHistory.displayRecords(d1).text(t1).ToString
         t_str = t_str + Text(t1) + vbNewLine
         row("Service Performed") = t_str
    Next
dt.Rows.Add(row)
```

HTML Part:

```
Private Function GetBody(ByVal dTable As DataTable) As String
        Dim dString As New StringBuilder

        dString.Append("<tbody>")

        For Each dRow As DataRow In dTable.Rows
            dString.Append("<tr align='center' valign='middle'>")
            For dCount As Integer = 0 To dTable.Columns.Count - 1
                If dCount = 0 Then
                    dString.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", dRow(dCount).ToShortDateString())
                ElseIf dCount = 2 Then
                    dString.AppendFormat("<td align='left'>{0}</td>", dRow(dCount))
                Else
                    dString.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", dRow(dCount))
                End If

            Next
            dString.Append("</tr>")
        Next
        dString.Append("</tbody>")

        Return dString.ToString()
    End Function
```

I am getting an output for "Service Performed" column as

'Pre-delivery inspection completed Wheel locks installed VIN glass etching vin etched'

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFJOU.jpg)

and not in separate line as

'Pre-delivery inspection completed
  Wheel locks installed
  VIN glass etching vin etched'

What will be the HTML table part of code to display multiline data received from Datatable column in HTML.

Comment: @ppradevan thakur, please check out the answer I have posted. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `vbNewLine` in your code by `<br>` since you are going to display DataTable values in a html table. Then your string will display in separate lines as you wanted it to.

The only change you need to make is in commented line in code below.

```
Dim row = dt.NewRow()
row("Date") = Display_Date
row("Mileage") = Odometer
    For t1 As Integer = 0 To returnData.serviceHistory.displayRecords(d1).text.Count - 1
         Text(t1) = returnData.serviceHistory.displayRecords(d1).text(t1).ToString
         t_str = t_str + Text(t1) & "<br>" ''replace vbNewLine with <br>
         row("Service Performed") = t_str
    Next
dt.Rows.Add(row)
```

Comment: Pradevan Thakur, you are welcome. Please mark it as answer.